# Spring cloud function application is unable to find function on AWS Lamdba

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to deploy my Spring Cloud Function on AWS Lamdba but it looks like my function
is not added to the function catalog, so I assume something is wrong with my bean registration but couldn't figure it out.

My Spring App:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TranscribeEventHandlerApplication implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      FunctionalSpringApplication.run(TranscribeEventHandlerApplication.class, args);
    }

    public Function<String, String> handle() {
      return value -> "OK";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
      context.registerBean("handle", FunctionRegistration.class, 
        () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(handle())
        .type(FunctionType.from(String.class).to(String.class).getType()));
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ai.alabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>transcribe-event-handler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>transcribe-event-handler</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.17.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Lamdba config:

- Runtime: Java 11 (Corretto)
- Handler: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker

From the log I can see that the application receives the test event and the defined handler handles it but it fails to find my function.

```
2021-07-07 01:16:12.932  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker      : Received: {"version":"0","id":"999cccaa-eaaa-0000-1111-123456789012","detail-type":"Transcribe Job State Change","source":"aws.transcribe","account":"123456789012","time":"2016-12-16T20:57:47Z","region":"us-east-1","resources":[],"detail":{"TranscriptionJobStatus":["COMPLETED"]}}
2021-07-07 01:16:12.962  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.adapter.aws.AWSLambdaUtils       : Incoming JSON Event: {"version":"0","id":"999cccaa-eaaa-0000-1111-123456789012","detail-type":"Transcribe Job State Change","source":"aws.transcribe","account":"123456789012","time":"2016-12-16T20:57:47Z","region":"us-east-1","resources":[],"detail":{"TranscriptionJobStatus":["COMPLETED"]}}
2021-07-07 01:16:13.129  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.adapter.aws.AWSLambdaUtils       : Incoming request headers: {id=22800a64-d3b5-000e-3be9-48418b185b32, timestamp=1625620572948}
```

When I don't set any environment variable I get this error `Failed to establish route, since neither were provided: 'spring.cloud.function.definition' as Message header or as application property or 'spring.cloud.function.routing-expression' as application property.`

When I set the environment variable `spring_cloud_function_routingExpression=handle` then I get this error `EL1008E: Property or field 'handle' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public or not valid?`.

When I set the environment variable `spring_cloud_function_definition=handle` then I get this error `Failed to lookup function to route based on the value of 'spring.cloud.function.definition' property 'handle'`

Comment: You should wrap `handle` in single quotes to signify literal (e.g., `spring_cloud_function_routingExpression='handle'`)

Comment: Gives me a new error.`"errorMessage": "Failed to lookup function to route to based on the expression ''handle'' whcih resolved to 'handle' function name."`

Comment: I ended up not using Spring but just the libraries provided by AWS and everything works well.

Comment: when it comes to lambda, spring seems to complicate. does not simplify :(

Answer (score 0):

**Function Component Scan**
Adding spring.cloud.function.scan.packages might help.

Reference: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_component_scan